# Formik disabled submit btn

Tags: reactjs, validation, form-submit, formik, yup

I have Formik form where `initialValues` are not empty for all fields. I have the following condition on my submit button:

```js
disabled={!(dirty && isValid)}
```

Yup validation schema:

```
const signInSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    title: Yup.string()
      .required(),
    description: Yup.string()
      .required(),
    spec: Yup.string()
      .required(),
    link: Yup.string()
      .url()
      .required(t),
  });
```

Why is the submit button disabled until I change value in some field? How can I make submit button enabled for this case if all `initialValues` are correct and I have not made any changes to the form fields?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that's what the dirty prop is meant to do. Check for changes on the initial state of the form.

Try removing it.

```
disabled={!isValid}
```